# is there any issue if I can see the application structure inside source window in console

Tags: angular, npm

I tried to find out the right answer for the question "what will happen if I can see the project structure inside source window of browser?". so far I did not get any proper answer for, that is the reason I am asking this question here. Hope somebody can help me on it.

let me try to explain the question here.

when we run angular application with "ng serve", we can be able to see the project structure inside source window of browser as shown in screenshot.
[image]

As per my information we use "ng serve" for development purpose as it helps and watches for the changes and rebuild and show the changes without running the application again.

my question is:

"what will happen if my production application is showing the same structure? will it opens the security risk for application?"

I really want to know the answer of it as I am working in an enterprise application and if any security risk is there, we will have to mitigate that as soon as possible, before anybody exploits it.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While running **ng serve** the application is running in development mode.
But when you build the application in production mode product structure will not be like that. There is no risk the same.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can create many different working environments. When run Local or Production or Staging mode. it will work differently. I think it will be less risky